# Python print de un for en txt

Tags: python, bucle-for, txt

Mi codigo lee un archivo en excel donde saca algunos datos y crea un texto con ellos, y replica este texto 170 veces con diferentes datos, necesito sacar la lista de esos textos en un txt, esta la ultima parte del codigo donde creo la el texto, pero no se como pasar cada uno a txt.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías usar un f-string.

Comment: Para facilitar la vida a los que te respondan, deberías copiar el código en texto, mejor que una imagen. Así los demás lo pueden probar.

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes abrir un archivo, que sea hace de la siguiente forma `output = open('output.txt', 'w')`.

La variable output hace referencia a un archivo llamado 'output.txt' y fue abierto con permisos de escritura. Ahora para guardar en cada linea del archivo lo que tienes que hacer es escribir en el archivo lo que tienes en el print, lo haces de la siguiente forma `output.write('el texto que deseas guardar')`.

Al finalizar es buena practica cerrar el archivo `output.close()`.

Hay que saber que si el archivo ya existe lo reescribirá y si no existe lo creara y escribirá en él todo lo del ciclo. Si quieres trabajar sobre un archivo existente la forma de abrirlo es la siguiente `output = open('output.txt', 'a')` que te posiciona en la ultima linea del archivo y puedes insertar contenido con el método write.

```py
output = open('output.txt','a')
for i in range(0, len(list_name)):
    correo = list_correo[i]
    name = list_name[i]
    date = fecha[i]
    placa = list_placa[i]
    firm = list_comp[i]
    output.write(f'Correo: {correo}\nBuen dia Sr {name}\nSeguros........\n\n')
output.close()
```

Comment: Es preferible usar `with` para abrir el archivo,`with open('output.txt', 'a') as output:`, y cuando salgas del _scope_ del `with`, se hará `output.close()` automáticamente, y no tendrás que llamarlo manualmente. Buena respuesta